# Save file path in MySQL database when uploading file to server

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie in PHP.

I compiled below PHP codes to re-size images in two size and it works great.

**My Question**

I need to save the uploaded image paths in MySQL database.

**Paths**

1) path to small image

2) path to big image

**This is the codes**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);

$change="";
$abc="";


 define ("MAX_SIZE","400");
 function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }

 $errors=0;


 if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {
    $image =$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


    if ($image) 
    {

        $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['file']['name']);

        $extension = getExtension($filename);
        $extension = strtolower($extension);


 if (($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
        {

            $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> ';
            $errors=1;
        }
        else
        {

 $size=filesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);


if ($size > MAX_SIZE*1024)
{
    $change='<div class="msgdiv">You have exceeded the size limit!</div> ';
    $errors=1;
}


if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile);

}
else if($extension=="png")
{
$uploadedfile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile);

}
else 
{
$src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile);
}

echo $scr;

list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);


$newwidth=150;
$newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
$tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);


$newwidth1=50;
$newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
$tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);

imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);

imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);


$filename = "profile.pic/profile/big" .date('Y-m-d_His - '). $_FILES['file']['name'];

$filename1 = "profile.pic/header/small".date('Y-m-d_His - '). $_FILES['file']['name'];



imagejpeg($tmp,$filename,100);

imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($tmp);
imagedestroy($tmp1);
}}

}

//If no errors registred, print the success message
 if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
 {

   // mysql_query("update {$prefix}users set img='$big',img_small='$small' where user_id='$user'");
    $change=' <div class="msgdiv">Image Uploaded Successfully!</div>';
 }

?>
```

**This is the Form**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en"><head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language">

        <title>picture demo</title>

       <link href="file:///C|/Users/Rameen/Downloads/.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <style type="text/css">
      .help
    {
    font-size:11px; color:#006600;
    }
    body {
        color: #000000;
        background-color:#999999 ;
        background:#999999 url(<?php echo $user_row['img_src']; ?>) fixed repeat top left;
        font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        }
    .msgdiv{
        width:759px;
        padding-top:8px;
        padding-bottom:8px;
        background-color: #fff;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:18px;-moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        }
    #container{width:763px;margin:0 auto;padding:3px 0;text-align:left;position:relative; -moz-border-radius: 6px;-webkit-border-radius: 6px; background-color:#FFFFFF;}</style>

      </head><body>
         <div align="center" id="err">
    <?php echo $change; ?>  </div>
       <div id="space"></div>





      <div id="container" >

       <div id="con">



            <table width="502" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="main">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td width="500" height="238" valign="top" id="main_right">

                  <div id="posts">
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php echo $filename; ?>" />  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="<?php echo $filename1; ?>"  />
                    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1">
                    <table width="500" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                   <tr><Td style="height:25px">&nbsp;</Td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="150"><div align="right" class="titles">Picture 
                : </div></td>
              <td width="350" align="left">
                <div align="left">
                  <input size="25" name="file" type="file" style="font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10pt" class="box"/>

                  </div></td>  
            </tr>
            <tr><Td></Td>
            <Td valign="top" height="35px" class="help">Image maximum size <b>400 </b>kb</span></Td>
            </tr>
            <tr><Td></Td><Td valign="top" height="35px"><input type="submit" id="mybut" value="       Upload        " name="Submit"/></Td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="200"><table width="200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">    
                  <tr>
                    <td width="200" align="center"><div align="left"></div></td>
                    <td width="100">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
              </table></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
                    </form>
          </div>
                  </td>            
                </tr>
              </tbody>
         </table>  
    </div>

      </div>
    </body></html>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you are still looking for answers?

Answer (score 0):

You should try `move_uploaded_file` function for both the images. Create two sepearte directories in your server and loop through both files and use the `move_uploaded_file`.

Also create two fields in your database for storing both paths. and dump both parts in it.

Comment: i have the directories but i just need to save that path in the MySQL server

Answer (score 0):

$path='upload/'.$_FILES['file']['name']; 
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] , $path); 
 mysql_query("insert into `tablename` (filepath) values('$path')");

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**   I need to save the uploaded image paths in MySQL database

And you have directories already so I think to will need to write a database query for this.

```
$yourDir = "path to your directory";
$completePathtoYourFile = $yourDir . "/" . $imageName . ".jpg";   //do not append .jpg if already.
```

Find how to connect to a mysql database.   [DB CONNECTION](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO table_name (field1, field2) VALUES ('$completePathtoYourFile', .......) ";
$result = mysqli_query($connectionVariable, $insert);
if(!$result){
   echo "Not Inserted..";
}
else{
   echo "Saved..";
}
```

As mentioned by other people you need to move the uploaded file from the temporary storage to a dir who's path is your **$yourDir**.

Comment: This is what i changed 
 $yourDir = "profile.pic/profile";
$completePathtoYourFile = $yourDir . "/" . $imageName . ".jpg";   //do not append .jpg if already.
 
 $insert = "INSERT INTO profiles (profile-pic, ProfileText) VALUES ('$completePathtoYourFile', .......) ";
$result = mysqli_query($connectionVariable, $insert);
if( !$result){
   echo "Not Inserted..";
}
else{
   echo "Saved..";
}

and it says saved but there is nothing in the database

Comment: can you edit your question and Post your attempt here ??

Comment: You need to write the path either absolute (complete path) or relative path. for ex: I have a code in folder named folder1 and dir to store images is another folder outside folder 1, so can write
$yourDir = "../folder2/";
$completePath = $yourDir. "/" . $imageName . ".jpg";

If it says Save that means the query is correct and DB connection is working

Comment: Thanks, profile.pic/profile is the directory and it is working but the path is not saving in the MySQL database.